# Problema com PHP XAMP no MAC OS X

Tags: php, xampp

Coloquei o php do XAMPP no path e está aparecendo este erro:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-       20131226/php_openssl.dll' -  dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-    20131226/php_openssl.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library'/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-  20131226/php_openssl.dll' -   dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-    20131226/php_openssl.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
>   PHP 5.6.8 (cli) (built: Apr 20 2015 10:59:03)
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies

Comment: O que você quer dizer com `Coloquei o php do XAMPP no path`?

Comment: nano /etc/paths e adiciono o caminho do php, dessa forma ele passa a ser um executável.